# display blob PNG image from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am building a webapp using jquery mobile and I have been trying to display a BLOB PNG image from MySQL DB but with no success. I would like to know what am I doing wrong.

This is my popup_data.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root' , '' , 'parkinglot');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$index_data = 1;
$tables = "show tables";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$tables);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM))
{    
    echo '
    <div data-role="popup" id="mapdata'.$index_data.'" class="ui-content" data-theme="a"> ';

    echo '<img src="showimage.php?sensor_num='.$index_data.'" />'; //sensor_num is to retrieve the image with that ID

    echo '    
    </div>
    ';
$index_data++;
};
?>
```

This is my showimage.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root' , '' , 'parkinglot');

// CHECK CONNECTION
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sensor_num = (isset($_GET['sensor_num']) && is_numeric($_GET['sensor_num'])) ? intval($_GET['sensor_num']) : 0;

$data = "SELECT * FROM $table_name2 WHERE sensor_num=$sensor_num";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$data);

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
   $imgData = $row2['picture'];
}
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $imgData;
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the image not showing up? Is the SQL query failing?

Comment: You should also consider that, if your $sensor_num is 0, you should return a 404 header rather than querying the database for sensor_num=0, or if there is a mysql error and you log the error. Consider using [Output Control](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to insure that only the intended headers/content are delivered.

Comment: The problem  is that the image is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

`$data = "SELECT * FROM $table_name2 WHERE sensor_num=$sensor_num";`

You do not set `$table_name2` anywhere inside showimage.php.